# Selected values only checked in the checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I tried this code but not working. Please, anyone help me.

```
var numbers = [649,583,613,670,520]; //checkbox values
    $.each(numbers,function(val,text) {
        $("input:checkbox").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
        });
```

Comment: Post your HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for you `checked` array and inside of `forEach()` you can use following methods.

## jQuery 1.6+

You can use the new [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop) method:

> **DEMO**

```js
var numbers = [649, 583, 613, 670, 520]; //checkbox values

numbers.forEach(v => {
//set checked using prop by passing true value
  $(`input:checkbox[value=${v}]`).prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="649">649<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="583">583<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="613">613<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="670">670<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="12">12<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="232">232<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="234">234<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="2343">2343<br />
```

---

## jQuery 1.5.x and below

The `.prop()` method is not available, so you need to use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr).

> **DEMO**

```js
var numbers = [649, 583, 613, 670, 520]; //checkbox values

numbers.forEach(v => {
//set checked using attr by passing true value
  $(`input:checkbox[value=${v}]`).attr("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="649">649<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="583">583<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="613">613<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="670">670<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="12">12<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="232">232<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="234">234<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="2343">2343<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is missing the `number` that it should be checked against. Something like the following will work:

```js
var numbers = [649,583,613,670,520];
$.each(numbers,function(index, number) {
  $("input:checkbox[value='"+number+"']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="600" />600<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="613" />613<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="649" />649
```

Note: always use `.prop()` when dealing with boolean attributes or properties, such as `disabled`, `checked`, `selected`, etc.